# Lost Ubuntu upon re-installing windows 7

Tags: 14.04

After re-installing Windows 7 I can't boot to Ubuntu anymore.

I keep getting message:

```
can't find `\Ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
```

Prior to the re-install there was no problem.

Comment: you had ubuntu installed using wubi??

Answer (score 0):

If you used the built-in restore function for Windows, it goes back to a "pristine" factory original install. Back to a time before it had to share anything with anybody.

Now that you have it working again (your call), re-install Ubuntu as previously because the factory restore of Windows shows no mercy --- Ubuntu is gone.